# problems with (root) / size

Tags: partition

When I installed ubuntu 20.04, I partitioned my SSD as follows: about 24.8 for `/` (root), 2gb for swap and left `/home` on the HDD (150gb).

But I started getting messages about the root storage being almost full. When I checked, there are two folders (`usr` and `var`) that take up a lot of space.

Would I have any way to move these folders to the `home` folder, or would I be able to move them to a new HD partition? (it could resize the HD and leave some space for those two folders). I am not aware of this issue, so I would like suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Use baobab to analize what is taking so much space, it could be something that's easy to clean. Make a screenshot of it and post it.

Comment: Cool, I managed to find some .zip files that are not being used. Thank you! I didn't know this command before.

Comment: You probably mean the root volume `/`, not `/root`.

Comment: Look at your snapd, 10gb. I don't know how it works, but sure it's taking too much space. Must have some automatic configuration that you have to disable.

Comment: Take a look at https://snapcraft.io/docs/snapshots

Answer (score 0):

You can use symlinks for this kind of problem, if you insist on staying with static partitions and not something like `lvm`.

For example (caution - make this change in single user mode where you don't need these trees to be available at all times):

```
cp -a /var /home/var
rm -rf /var
ln -s home/var /var
```

Debian (and hence Ubuntu) packages have no problem with following symlinks to existing directories.

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by single user mode?

Comment: Hi, when booting (right after BIOS or EFI) hit a key (I think ESC) to get a boot menu, which lets you choose among different ways to start up.  One of those should be "recovery mode" or "single user mode", selecting that will lead to the environment I mean.  In short: you get a root shell, nothing else is started, and all filesystems are read only (you'll have to change the last - I can help you with that once you get past the menu).